# Cache only specific tables in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, caching

I have a table with millions of rows (with 98% reads, maybe 1 - 2% writes) which has references to couple of other config tables (with maybe 20 entries each). What are the best practices for caching the tables in this case? I cannot cache the table with millions of rows. But at the same time, I also don't want to hit the DB for the config tables. Is there a work around for this? I'm using Spring boot, and the data is in postgres.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me refer to this:

> What are the best practices for caching the tables in this case

I don't think you should "cache tables" as you say. In the Application, you work with the data, and this is what should be cached. This means the object that you cache should be already in a structure that includes these relations. Of course, in order to fetch the whole object from the database, you can use JOINs, but when the object gets cached, it doesn't matter already, the translation from Relational model to the object model was done.

Now the question is too broad because the actual answer can vary on the technologies you use, nature of data, and so forth.

You should answer the following questions before you design the cache (the list is out my head, but hopefully you'll get the idea):

- What is the cache invalidation strategy? You say, there are 2% writes, what happens if the data gets updated, the data in the cache may become stale. Is it ok?
- A kind of generalization of the previous question: If you have multiple instances (JVMs) of the same application, and one of them triggered the update to the DB data, what should happen to other apps' caches?
- How long the stale/invalid data can reside in the cache?
- Do the use cases of your application access all the data from the tables with the same frequencies or some data is more "interesting" (for example, the oldest data is not read, but the latest data is always "hot")? Probably if its millions of data for configuration, the JVM doesn't have all these objects in the heap at the same time, so there should be some "slice" of this data...

  - What are the performance implications of having the cache? How does it affect the GC behavior?
- What technologies can be used in your case (maybe due to some regulations/licensing, some technologies are just not available, this is more a case in large organizations)

Based on these observations you can go with:

1. In-memory cache:
    Spring integrates with various in-memory cache technologies, you can also use them without spring at all, to name a few:

   - Google Guava cache (for older spring cache implementations)
   - Coffeine (for newer spring cache implementations)
   - In memory map of key / value
2. In memory but in another process:

   - Redis
   - Infinispan
     Now, these caches are slower than those listed in the previous category but still can 
     be significantly faster than the DB.
3. Data Grids:

   - Hazelcast
4. Off heap memory-based caches (this means that you store the data off-heap, so its not eligible for garbage collection)
5. Postgres related solutions. For example, you can still go to db, but since you can opt for keeping the index in-memory the queries will be significantly faster.
6. Some ORM mapping specific caches (like hibernate has its cache as well).
7. Some kind of mix of all above.
8. Implement your own solution - well, this is something that probably you shouldn't do as the first attempt to address the issue, because caching can be tricky.

In the end, let me provide a link to some very interesting [session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NLS7147UQo) given by Michael Plod about caching. I believe it will help you to find the solution that works for you best.